# how can i get back in my phone

Tags: locked-out

I was playing around with my phone lock app and put in a pin password I later turn back on my phone and realized I forgot my pin I have no idea what to do will i still be able to get back in my phone I have tried turning it on and off,holding the power button with the lower volume sign nothing worked.

Comment: What phone? Android version?

Comment: I never use pins to unlock keyboards, but in pattern unlocking there was a choice where you were authenticating yourself with your google credentials. Not sure if it is applicable in android 4. So, if you are in Android 2, try many times.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter your pin incorrectly a number of times, the device should present you with a temporary time lock. If you continue to enter it incorrectly you should be prompted to login with the Google account associated with your device to disable the lock.